# Ubuntu network performance on over 2k connections

Tags: networking

I'm using an EC2 c3.8xlarge Ubuntu 14.04 LTS machine with over 3k threads simultaneously downloading web pages one after another.

Although this machine should have a 10Gb network performance, I can't get it to perform higher than 10MB/s.

IS there any way I can improve the network speed of my machine?

my /etc/sysctl.conf

```
net.core.rmem_max = 16777216
net.core.wmem_max = 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 0
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 0
fs.file-max = 262144
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 60
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 30
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians = 0
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1024 65000
net.core.somaxconn = 1024
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 87380 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 65536 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_mem = 16777216 16777216 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_max_orphans = 262144
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 2000
net.ipv4.route.flush=1
```

Answer (score 0):

> 3k threads simultaneously

There is your problem.  You need to redesign your application to not use an insane number of threads, which are all competing with one another for resources.  See `io_submit()` and friends for how to send the kernel an IO request without blocking the thread until it completes.  You can also use `setsockopt()` to set the kernel buffer size to zero so that it won't waste time copying data back and forth between your buffers and its own.  Of course, you will need to make sure to give it multiple pending IO requests at the same time so that as soon as it finishes one it already has another to move on to completing.  By doing this, you can have a single thread ( or one per cpu core anyhow ) manage all of the IO on thousands of connections without the overhead of switching between thousands of threads.